# Existence and uniqueness of integral equation of convolution type

Tags: integration

Consider the Fredholm integral equation of the first kind with convolution type kernel
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x-y)u(y)dy = f(x)$

Suppose $f$ and $k$ belongs to $L^{1}(R)$ what is the necessary and sufficient condition to have a unique solution in $L^{1}(R)$.